# How to tune this ontology for simple geometric shape recognition?

Tags: rdf, ontology, inference, shape-recognition

I've the following ontology where red links are `DatatypeProperties`, blue ones are `ObjectProperties` and black ones 'is_a' relations. The ontology simply represent `POINT`, `COORDONATES` and `SHAPES` concepts.

I'm interested in doing geometric shape recognition with this ontology.

Let's says that we have four instances of `POINT` : **point0**, **point1**, **point2** and **point3**, with proper coodonates and all related with the property `is-contained-in` to an instance of `SHAPE` called **shape0**.

What is necessary in this ontology to infer that according to points coordonates, **shape0** is a `SQUARE` instead of being a `RECTANGLE`?

in other words how to introduce recognition capabilities in the ontology.

[image]

Comment: Not sure what exactly you want...you may need to have rules for finding out the shape. e.g: if it is a square then it has four lines of symmetry and a rectangle has two.

Comment: That is a good start. How to formulate such rules?

Comment: you can use SWRL/SPARQL to write such rules. you can write them using protege if you are using Protege to build ontologies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just giving an example, how it can be written as a swrl rule. Please note that this is not tested and may not be accurate. so, consider this as only a clue.

Shape(?s),hasCordinates(?s,c1),hasCordinates(?s,c2),hasx(?c1,?x1),hasy(?c1,?y1),subtract(?x1,?y1,?diff1),hasx(?c2,?x2),hasy(?c2,?y2),subtract(?x2,?y2,?diff2),pow(?diff1, 2, ?sq1),pow(?diff2, 2, ?sq2),add(sq1,sq2,?sum1).....(?sum2).....-> issquare(?s)

Please note that there would be more efficient ways to do this.

Comment: A shape does not have a coordinate so your relation hasCordinates(?s,c1) sounds not correct to me.

Comment: In you case, Shape has a point and that point has coordinates..like hasPoint(?s,?p1), hasCordinates(?p1,?c1)...As I told you this is only example; you have to explore further...